# Polymorphism with Distribution in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I have a problem where I want a single object to represent any distribution class (polymorphism) used in random library in c++11. Since distribution does not have a common base class as far as I know I am using factory pattern to solve my problem. Is there a better way to do so ? I am adding the code below which has some errors

```
#include <iostream>
#include<random>

using namespace std;

class Distribution 
{
public:
    void *distribution;
    virtual void get_distribution() = 0;
};

class normal_dist: public Distribution
{
public:
    //normal_distribution<double> *distribution;
    void get_distribution()
    {
        distribution = new normal_distribution<double>(5.0,2.0); 
    }
};

class uniform_real_dist: public Distribution
{
public:
    //uniform_real_distribution<double> *distribution;
    void get_distribution()
    {
        distribution = new uniform_real_distribution<double>(0.0,1.0);
    }
};

class Helper
{
public:
    Distribution *dist;
    default_random_engine generator;

Helper(string dist_type) 
{
    if(dist_type == "normal")
    {
        dist = new normal_dist;
        dist->get_distribution();
    }
}
};


int main() {

Helper *help = new Helper("normal");
cout<<(*(help->dist->distribution))(help->generator);


// your code goes here
return 0;
}
```

My questions are three fold

1) Is there a base class of distribution

2) if no, is there a way to create polymorphism

3) Whether the above code is correct approach and what is the bug and how to solve this. I would be very thankful if someone could help me on this

Comment: If I had to guess from your code, I would say you come from a java or C# background. In C++ using `new` is almost always an error, bug or anti-pattern. using `void*` is another huge red flag.

Comment: Thank you @bolov for the answer. It really helped a lot. Can you please tell me some resources other than the standard books how to improve my designing and coding skills. I would be very thankful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Is there a base class of distribution

Nope. C++ - unlike Java or C# - is not an OOP language. It's a multi-paradigm language. Instead of a base class for everything, C++ uses metaprogramming instead whenever possible. For instance, there isn't a base class for all containers. Functions wanting to accept as parameters containers, don't have base class as argument. Instead you write a template functions which is capable of handling any kind of range.

> 2) if no, is there a way to create polymorphism

Yes, ofcourse, but it's oh not so simple as it might seem at first glance.

> 3) Whether the above code is correct approach and what is the bug and how to solve this. I would be very thankful if someone could help me on this

First, don't use explicit `new` in C++. And don't use raw pointers to model ownership. In C++ we use the RAII principle and as such we use smart pointers when pointers who *own* resources are needed.

Second, don't use `void*`. If you really need type erasure, use `std::any` which, admittedly is cumbersome to use at the moment, but it offers a type safe type erasure.

---

So, instead of trying to fix your compile problems - which wouldn't have fixed your design, I instead created one implementation version of the polymorphism.

When we embark on this task, the first issue that we come across is: different types in the distribution generator function (`operator()`). For once, different distributions can get different types (`int`, `float` etc). Then, we need a generator - which is template - to call it. These make it impossible to simply create a virtual function which we can override.

For returning different types you need `std::variant`. Because implementing is already difficult, I will do this in the second example.

For the generator, there are ways to get away with simpler designs. I chose to store a pointer to a generator in the derived distribution. This encodes the type of the generator in the distribution, but in many scenarios can be acceptable. Another, longer way would be to create polymorphic versions of the generators.

So this is the first example working with a vector of polymorphic int distributions. In the example the vector stores uniform, binomial and poisson distributions to see the polymorphism at work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Base_int_distribution
{
public:
    virtual int generate() = 0;
    virtual ~Base_int_distribution() = default;
};

template <class Eng, class D>
class Int_distribution : public Base_int_distribution
{
    std::shared_ptr<Eng> engine_;
    D distribution_;

public:
    template <class... Args>
    Int_distribution(std::shared_ptr<Eng> engine, Args... args)
        : engine_{std::move(engine)},
          distribution_{args...} {}

    Int_distribution(const Int_distribution&) = default;
    Int_distribution(Int_distribution&&) = default;

    Int_distribution& operator=(const Int_distribution&) = default;
    Int_distribution& operator=(Int_distribution&&) = default;

    int generate() override { return distribution_(*engine_); }
};

// some alias helpers, because oh boy, does it get crazy with the types

template <class Gen>
using Uniform_int_dist_poly = Int_distribution<Gen, std::uniform_int_distribution<int>>;

template <class Gen>
using Binomial_int_dist_poly = Int_distribution<Gen, std::binomial_distribution<int>>;

template <class Gen>
using Poisson_int_dist_poly = Int_distribution<Gen, std::poisson_distribution<int>>;
```

```
int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;  
    auto eng = std::make_shared<std::mt19937>(rd());

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base_int_distribution>> distributions{};
    // nope, we can't use initializer list, don't get me started

    distributions.push_back(std::make_unique<Uniform_int_dist_poly<std::mt19937>>(eng, -50, 50));
    distributions.push_back(std::make_unique<Binomial_int_dist_poly<std::mt19937>>(eng, 4, .05));
    distributions.push_back(std::make_unique<Poisson_int_dist_poly<std::mt19937>>(eng, 4.));

    // for each distribution
    for (auto& dist : distributions)
    {
        // get 10 numbers
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            std::cout << dist->generate() << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

> ```
> 21 0 -43 2 -37 -38 39 42 -37 46 
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
> 5 4 7 6 5 6 6 4 1 8
> ```

Next, I modified this to work with the standard arithmetic types and I used `long long`, `double` and `int` in the example, along with all the previous different distributions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <variant>

using DistTs = std::variant<
    signed char, unsigned char, char,
    short, int, long, long long,
    unsigned short, unsigned int, unsigned long, unsigned long long,
    float, double, long double>;

class Base_distribution
{
public:
    virtual DistTs generate() = 0;
    virtual ~Base_distribution() = default;
};

template <class Eng, class D>
class Distribution : public Base_distribution
{
    std::shared_ptr<Eng> engine_;
    D distribution_;

public:
    template <class... Args>
    Distribution(std::shared_ptr<Eng> engine, Args... args)
        : engine_{std::move(engine)},
          distribution_{args...} {}

    Distribution(const Distribution&) = default;
    Distribution(Distribution&&) = default;

    Distribution& operator=(const Distribution&) = default;
    Distribution& operator=(Distribution&&) = default;

    DistTs generate() override { return distribution_(*engine_); }
};

// some alias helpers, because oh boy, does it get crazy with the types

template <class Gen, class T = int>
using Uniform_int_dist_poly = Distribution<Gen, std::uniform_int_distribution<T>>;

template <class Gen, class T = double>
using Uniform_real_dist_poly = Distribution<Gen, std::uniform_real_distribution<T>>;

template <class Gen, class T = int>
using Binomial_dist_poly = Distribution<Gen, std::binomial_distribution<T>>;

template <class Gen, class T = int>
using Poisson_int_dist_poly = Distribution<Gen, std::poisson_distribution<T>>;
```

```
int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;  
    auto eng = std::make_shared<std::mt19937>(rd());

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base_distribution>> distributions{};
    // nope, we can't use initializer list, don't get me started

    distributions.push_back(std::make_unique<Uniform_int_dist_poly<std::mt19937, long long>>(eng, -50, 50));
    distributions.push_back(std::make_unique<Uniform_real_dist_poly<std::mt19937, double>>(eng, -2.0, 2.0));
    distributions.push_back(std::make_unique<Binomial_dist_poly<std::mt19937>>(eng, 4, .05));
    distributions.push_back(std::make_unique<Poisson_int_dist_poly<std::mt19937>>(eng, 4.));

    // for each distribution
    for (auto& dist : distributions)
    {
        // get 10 numbers
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            std::visit([](auto e) { std::cout << e << " "; }, dist->generate());
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

> ```
> 8 -25 29 14 -17 -6 -16 18 32 16 
> 0.683707 0.2806 -1.00301 1.89474 1.19426 0.069856 -0.354233 1.1193 0.0319062 -1.69658 
> 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
> 3 4 5 5 2 8 3 8 1 5
> ```

---

If you need a factory pattern, that can easily be made on top of this.

---

As you can see, it's ... let's say ... not trivial to make distributions polymorphic. And you need to make some choices regarding your design, and whichever choice you take, you make a compromise.

So you really need to analyze if it's indeed worth it. Only you can answer this question. At least now you have a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

If you know which distribution is applicable in which scenario then using template is better approach. Here is sample code for the same :

```
template<class C, template <class> class M>
M<C> getDistributionObject(const C& arg1, const C& arg2)
{
   return M<C>(arg1,arg2);
}
int main() {

auto normalDistribution = getDistributionObject<double,normal_distribution>(5.0,2.0); 
return 0;
}
```

Comment: never use explicit `new` and never use raw pointers to model ownership (at least not in user code).

Comment: I must confess I am impressed. Good job! I have removed the down-vote. However, I can't upvote your answer because I don't see the point of using smart pointers since you are not using polymorphism. If you could explain in your post what is the purpose of having smart pointers instead of value objects. Then again, the OP doesn't explain what it is he/she needs so ...

Comment: @bolov you are right that since I am not using polymorphism so it doesn't make any sense to use pointers, so updated my answer again without pointers